# An explanation of the arithmetic use of models of Shimura varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the articles I browse that talk about the construction of local models of Shimura varieties, I often see them say things like "These models are useful arithemtically for the calculation of the semi-simple zeta function by means of the Lefchetz Trace Formula..... (etc etc)" but can not seem to find a source on the topic.

Can someone expand on this a little? Or provide a source for me to read?

Comment: I personally like https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/ag/alggeom/preprints/redshi.pdf